# Problema al usar variable en consulta PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo una web en la cual quiero pasar una variable de una página a otra pero solo consigo que me reconozca el ID de la base de datos, cuando le cambio el parámetro no me muestra nada. Os paso el código que me funciona y también el código que me da problemas.

Éste código funciona:

```
<a href="visualizar-informe-alta.php?id=<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><img src="images/ver-paciente.png" alt="Ver Informe" height="25" width="25"   title="Visualizar Informe"></a>

<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])=="")
    {   
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
    else{

$id=intval($_GET['id']);

?>


<?php 

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `fecha_alta`, `cip_paciente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `edad`, `sexo`, `servicio`, `modalidad`, `up_que_consulta`, `cod_grupo_patologia`, `cod_cie9`, `dolor`, `fuerza`, `movilidad`, `dependencia`, `otros_parametros`, `motivo_alta` FROM `informe_de_alta` WHERE id=:id";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($results as $result)

?>
```

---

Éste código es el que no me funciona:

```
<a href="visualizar-informe-alta.php?cip_paciente=<?php echo htmlentities($result->cip_paciente);?>"><img src="images/ver-paciente.png" alt="Ver Informe" height="25" width="25"   title="Visualizar Informe"></a>

<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])=="")
    {   
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
    else{

$cip_paciente=intval($_GET['cip_paciente']);

?>


<?php 

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `fecha_alta`, `cip_paciente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `edad`, `sexo`, `servicio`, `modalidad`, `up_que_consulta`, `cod_grupo_patologia`, `cod_cie9`, `dolor`, `fuerza`, `movilidad`, `dependencia`, `otros_parametros`, `motivo_alta` FROM `informe_de_alta` WHERE cip_paciente=:cip_paciente";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':cip_paciente',$cip_paciente,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($results as $result)

?>
```

¿Qué pudiera ser?

Comment: ¿Da algún error? ¿Seguro que estás recibiendo un dato correcto en el GET? ¿Qué arroja `var_dump($cip_paciente);`? ¿Qué arroja `var_dump($results);` ?... Acostumbra a depurar tus variables **esenciales**, para saber lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla).

Answer (score -1):

en la parte de la consulta donde estas haciendo los WHERE ne vez de mandarlas con los dos puntos pq no las mandas con los de interrogacion, ya que tu estas enviando parametros, seria algo mas o menos asi

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `fecha_alta`, `cip_paciente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `edad`, `sexo`, `servicio`, `modalidad`, `up_que_consulta`, `cod_grupo_patologia`, `cod_cie9`, `dolor`, `fuerza`, `movilidad`, `dependencia`, `otros_parametros`, `motivo_alta` FROM `informe_de_alta` WHERE id=?";
```

esta seria la primera consulta la segunda quedaria asi

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `fecha_alta`, `cip_paciente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `edad`, `sexo`, `servicio`, `modalidad`, `up_que_consulta`, `cod_grupo_patologia`, `cod_cie9`, `dolor`, `fuerza`, `movilidad`, `dependencia`, `otros_parametros`, `motivo_alta` FROM `informe_de_alta` WHERE cip_paciente=?";
```

recomendable que le hagas un echo antes de mandarlos a la vista para ver si te trae el resultado.

Comment: Hola Juan, el cambiar el interrogante por un marcador de posición no afecta al resultado.

Comment: ps si pero yo asi  lo utilizo siempre puede ser ese error jejeeje

Comment: Ese no es el error, si el dato está bien la consulta debería funcionar. El error es más bien o que no está recibiendo bien la variable o un error en la consulta misma o simplemente que la consulta no arroja resultados. Si usa el marcador de posición y luego hace esto: `$query->bindParam(':cip_paciente',$cip_paciente,PDO::PARAM_STR);` entonces tendrá **otro error**, como podrás comprender.

Comment: ps si el error esta en la consulta al cambiar de id quiere decir que no le esta enviando la antigual id, creo yo